# Removing specular intensity from all materials with internal

Tags: python, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I've ripped a model from a video game and for whatever reason whenever I import the .obj file all of the materials have an unwanted default specular intensity of 1.000 (I am using the internal Blender Render engine.)

There are thousands of materials, so is there a way to set the intensity to 0.000 for all materials without doing it manually one by one?

This seems to me to be a job for a python script but I'm unfamiliar with both python and scripting inside of blender (maybe I'm wrong about that, anyway).

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: For Cycles and Eeve refer to: [removing speculuar intensity from all materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/206759/removing-specular-intensity-from-all-materials-2-9?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

copy the script below, add a new text block, paste, right click, run script.  The specular intensity of all materials will be set to 0.

```
import bpy

for m in bpy.data.materials:
    m.specular_intensity = 0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I knew it was probably very simple. Will accept in uh... 4 minutes?