# Removing specular intensity from all materials (2.9)

Tags: materials

Would anyone be so kind as to write a script that sets everything in the scene to use 0.0 specular for 2.9? I tried the script here: [Removing specular intensity from all materials with internal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42858/removing-specular-intensity-from-all-materials-with-internal/206758#206758) but then realized after that it's not going to work in 2.9.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shamesly copied from:

[Automatically change the properties of multiple materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195671/automatically-change-the-properties-of-multiple-materials)

```
import bpy
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if not mat.use_nodes:
        mat.specular_intensity = 0
        continue
    for n in mat.node_tree.nodes:
        if n.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED':
            n.inputs["Specular"].default_value = 0
```

Please refer to the
Blender api
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Material.html#bpy.types.Material.specular_intensity